How do you attack this C doubly linked list through control flow hijacking and buffer overflow?
The attack target
The attack target is a C program which uses a doubly linked list:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
    char data[32];
} Node;

Node *list_insert(Node *after)
{
    Node *node = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    if (after) {
        node->prev = after;
        if (after->next) {
            node->next = after->next;
            node->next->prev = node;
        }
        after->next = node;
    }

    return node;
}

void list_delete(Node *node)
{
    if (node->prev) {
        node->prev->next = node->next;
    }
    if (node->next) {
        node->next->prev = node->prev;
    }
}

int _main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Need three command-line arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Node *a = list_insert(0);
    Node *b = list_insert(a);
    Node *c = list_insert(b);

    strcpy(a->data, argv[1]);
    strcpy(b->data, argv[2]);
    strcpy(c->data, argv[3]);

    list_delete(c);
    list_delete(b);
    list_delete(a);

    return 0;
}

Setup
OS = Linux
ISA = x86_32

addr_of_a = 0x080002e0
addr_of_b = 0x08000320
addr_of_c = 0x08000350
ret = 0xfffe8764 # the return address of the list_delete function (returns to _main)

My current progress
Apparently, the vulnerability is the char data[32] buffer inside each linked list node that could be overflown. My current plan is to:

Overflow b->data until it reaches c, then overwrite c->prev with ret-0x4 and overwrite c->next with the address of c->data (this makes c->next point to its data region which I want to inject the shellcode to).
list_delete(c) is called, then the line node->prev->next = node->next is executed. Given the setup in step 1, This line would inject the address of c->data in place of list_delete's return address.
This step is where I'm stuck on: the code in the next if statement node->next->prev = node->prev is executed and the first word in my shellcode is overwritten with node->prev(value = ret-4). I can't avoid this by setting node->next to null because I need to set node->next to a pointer to data in order to overwrite the return address on stack. I realized that with this method, whatever address I set c->next to, the content it's pointing to would always get its first 4 bytes would always get overwritten.

What did I miss? Did I understand any concepts wrong? Or is this attack supposed to be much harder than I thought?
I have spent so many hours on this homework and am currently hard stuck. If anyone could help me out it'd be much appreciated!

You mentioned your shellcode is written to c->data. Is the heap executable?

Yes. This problem is specifically compiled with most security measures disabled

Use the second if to hijack the execution (i.e. c->next as the pointer to the return address and c->prev as the pointer to the shellcode). This way the second DWORD of your shellcode is written and you can jump around it with a short branch as the first instruction of your shellcode. This is how the unlink technique on dlmalloc was being used IIRC.
